# SharpDevelop does not save changes in WXS file

Tags: wix, sharpdevelop

I open *.wxs file in SharpDevelop and made layout of controls (Text aligned to right, move etc). Then clicked Save All.
Reopen this file and see that all changes were lost. How can I align and resize controls on my WiX form?

Comment: This should not be happening the changes should have been saved. I tried various things but could not reproduce it but I am probably not doing exactly the same steps as you are. Would you be able you tell me which version of SharpDevelop you are using and the exact steps to reproduce the problem?